# How can I share my wired internet connection via the wireless adapter on my Satellite A50-543?

Tags: wireless, internet-connection

I have an old laptop which currently runs WindowsXP.

I have got recently an Android phone with just WiFi. Now I want to use my laptop as bridge (via WiFi), so that I can connect from my Android to internet through laptop.

Because WindowsXP does not support Access Point (AP) mode, I can't use it with  android.

I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu on the laptop. Will it work? And how to do it?

Here are the specs of the [laptop](http://gulf.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?LNG=13&service=AE&PRODUCT_ID=95811&DISC_MODEL=1).